# Ranining Cubes to form shape

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, collision

[This is the .blend file I'm working with](https://www.dropbox.com/s/55mzfuek77s7mc2/batman06.blend?dl=0)

I created this model with a processing sketch that translated colors into volumes. Now I'd like to have a rain of cubes, having the cubes to land in their proper position to build the batman image. How can I do this? animation node? collisions?[image: Render of attached object]

Comment: Why can't you just animate them to fall to those positions. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried adding gravity to the object, but I want the cubes to fall not all at once. I could animate them manually, but it's hundreds of cubes.

Answer (score 2):

You can evaluate a *Delay Falloff* and use a multiple of the output as the z location of the objects as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

You may also randomize the order using the *Offsets* input.